# http basic authentication with different rights

Tags: node.js, nginx, basic-authentication

I am in middle of a development, and havent so far created user authentication in my node.js application,however I have an admin back-end where I do not want the users provided with the username and password.

I am looking for a way to implement basic http authentication but depending on the credentials provided, they can or can not go to different areas of site, in short: I want different credentials for admin page.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks and regards,
Babar

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want two different types of testers. One to test frontend, but not affect backend and one that also affects backend.

I would actually run two instances of Node and point the testers to two different urls.

And in your routes you check the environment, giving fake responses to "testers1" and actual backend respones to "testers2".

Like:

```
NODE_ENV=simulated node server

function (req, res) {
   if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'simulated') {
     // Give fake response
   } else {
     // Get from backend
   }
}
```

Comment: That is the intended final form, but right now I have not created any users and users will not be implemented until asked by the management, I dont want to let the app testers through to the admin side. Hence i want to create two kind of username, password pairs, one for one kind of links, and other for admin links.

Comment: Hm, could you add more specific examples? Like a "user story"? What should a user be able to do? Sorry, I am not quite understanding the scenario.

Comment: Okie, Lets say I have two team of testers, tester1 and tester2, tester1 needs to test the front end, and tester2 backend. if I create a basic HTTP authentication tester1 can go to backend of the website and interfere with tester2s test cases and vice versa, i want to create two Http basic authentication, one for frontend of site, other for backend of site

Comment: Aha, I think I understand. Just to be clear. You want tester1 to use the frontend, testing it running on Node with all its routes, but you do not want those routes to actually go to the backend which tester2 is testing? Is tester2 also testing via the interface of the app? Both testers test the same stuff, only tester2 actually interacts with the backend?

Comment: ah, okay, sorry. Good luck finding a solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple location blocks and separate access files or something like this:

```
location /test/ {
    auth_basic            "Test";
    auth_basic_user_file  /access.txt;
    root '/webroot/$remote_user';
}
```

Comment: I went with middleware, and created similar logic but hardcoded the username and passwords, thanks thought I will look into this as well, but for now, I have coded it so with just few tweaks it will work when actual user profiles will be created :)